# getting problem after fetching custom field in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

After fetching the custom checkbox field from the opportunity, getting underline below the checkbox. How to remove this underline?

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
 <aura:attribute name="sObjectInfo" type="Opportunity"/>
  <aura:attribute name="fieldsArray" type="List" default="['Mycheck__c']"/>
  <lightning:recordForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Opportunity" 

                      mode="readonly" fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"/>
  </aura:component>
```

Comment: You can apply CSS for `text-decoration: none;` hope this might resolve the issue.

Comment: Can u please  tell me in which tag I have to apply css..?

Comment: I have got the solution...we have to apply "mode=edit" to remove the underline.

Comment: you can create style file(.css) in the component